# How to play several fragments of mp3 synchronously?

Tags: javafx-2

It's my second question about JavaFX. I am sorry cause I am not an experienced Java programmer and quite a novice with JavaFX. I don't understand previous answer thoroughly and will read it again and again later. But now I have the next question. I rewrite my program as follows:

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.scene.media.Media;
 import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
 import javafx.stage.Stage; import javafx.util.Duration;

 public class JavaFXMediaPlayer05 extends Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }

     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException, InterruptedException {
         Media media = new Media("file:///D:/1016_00.mp3");
 //Set and play the first fragment of mp3-file
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer(media);
         mediaPlayer1.setStartTime(Duration.millis(1219.0));
         mediaPlayer1.setStopTime(Duration.millis(2728.0));
         mediaPlayer1.play();
         System.out.println("1st fragment played!");
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
 //Set and play the second fragment
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer(media);
         mediaPlayer2.setStartTime(Duration.millis(3947.0));
         mediaPlayer2.setStopTime(Duration.millis(6629.0));
         mediaPlayer2.play();
         System.out.println("2nd fragment played!");
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
 //Set and play the third fragment
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer3 = new MediaPlayer(media);
         mediaPlayer3.setStartTime(Duration.millis(7453.0));
         mediaPlayer3.setStopTime(Duration.millis(10704.0));
         mediaPlayer3.play();
         System.out.println("3rd fragment played!");
 //Just sleep
         System.out.println("pre-sleep");
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
         System.out.println("after-sleep");
     }
 }
```

And I debug it in NetBeans step-by-step. I get a strange result. I hear the sound not at mediaplayer.play() but only at the end of method start(). All 3 fragments play at once. How do I manage them to play sequentially? Do I have to fire method start() many times - one time for every fragment? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

`MediaPlayer` starts playing media asynchronously. So all your `mediaPlayerN.play()` happen simultaneously.

You can use `Timeline` to start playing at specific time, see below.

Also as you have only 1 media for all players you can use same `MediaPlayer` for all samples. Just note you should use `seek()` method instead of `setStartTime()` in this case.

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer(media);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, "plays at start", new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            mediaPlayer1.setStartTime(Duration.millis(1219.0));
            mediaPlayer1.setStopTime(Duration.millis(2728.0));
            mediaPlayer1.play();
        }
    }),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), "plays after 5 seconds", new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            mediaPlayer1.seek(Duration.millis(3947.0));
            mediaPlayer1.setStopTime(Duration.millis(6629.0));
            mediaPlayer1.play();
        }
    }),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), "plays after 10 seconds", new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            mediaPlayer1.seek(Duration.millis(7453.0));
            mediaPlayer1.setStopTime(Duration.millis(10704.0));
            mediaPlayer1.play();
        }
    })
);
timeline.play();
```